# Change inheritance to OneToOne‍ relation in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-inheritance

I have models that have a `inheritance relationship`. I want to turn this relationship into a `OneToOne‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍` relationship, **without removing any data in project.**

This is structure of models:

```
class BaseFieldsModel(models.Model):
    create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    update_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    created_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='created_%(class)ss')  
    updated_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='updated_%(class)ss')  

class User(AbstractBaseUser,BaseFieldsModel):
    # Some fields


class Teacher(User):
    # Some fields

class Student(User): 
    # Some fields
```

All things was good until I want to resructure my database because of this problem that I had in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223580/control-object-creation-flow-in-django-inheritance-models) design. In new DB model, I want to have something like this: (OneToOne Relation)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,BaseFieldsModel):
    # Some fields


class Teacher(BaseFieldsModel):
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='student_user')
    # Some fields

class Student(BaseFieldsModel): 
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='teacher_user')
    # Some fields
```

So I did run `makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'UserManager':
  UserManager/migrations/0022_auto_20200425_1233.py
    - Change managers on student
    - Change managers on teacher
    - Add field create_date to student
    - Add field created_by to student
    - Add field update_date to student
    - Add field updated_by to student
    - Add field create_date to teacher
    - Add field created_by to teacher
    - Add field update_date to teacher
    - Add field updated_by to teacher
    - Alter field user_ptr on student
    - Alter field user_ptr on teacher
```

and then run `migrate` and got this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'create_date' in class 'Student' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'.
```

**# Tested solutions**

**1.first failed solution:**

Create `Teacher` and `Student` without  inheritance form `BaseFielsModel`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,BaseFieldsModel):
    # Some fields


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='student_user')

    create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    update_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    created_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='created_%(class)ss')  
    updated_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='updated_%(class)ss')  

    # Some other fields

class Student(models.Model): 
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='teacher_user')

    create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    update_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    created_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='created_%(class)ss')  
    updated_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='updated_%(class)ss')  

    # Some other fields
```

Then run `makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'UserManager':
  UserManager/migrations/0022_auto_20200425_1240.py
    - Change managers on student
    - Change managers on teacher
    - Add field create_date to student
    - Add field created_by to student
    - Add field update_date to student
    - Add field updated_by to student
    - Add field create_date to teacher
    - Add field created_by to teacher
    - Add field update_date to teacher
    - Add field updated_by to teacher
    - Alter field user_ptr on student
    - Alter field user_ptr on teacher
```

Then `migrate` and again raise error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'create_date' in class 'Student' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'.
```

**2.Second failed solution:**

Create `Teacher` and `Student` without `BaseFielsModel` and its fields:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,BaseFieldsModel):
    # Some fields


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='student_user')

    # Some other fields

class Student(models.Model): 
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='teacher_user')
    # Some other fields
```

Then run `makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'UserManager':
  UserManager/migrations/0022_auto_20200425_1243.py
    - Change managers on student
    - Change managers on teacher
    - Alter field user_ptr on student
    - Alter field user_ptr on teacher
```

and run `migrate`:

```
 Applying UserManager.0022_auto_20200425_1243... OK
```

Then add these fields to `Student` and `Teacher`:

```
create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    update_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    created_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='created_%(class)ss')  
    updated_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='updated_%(class)ss')
```

Then run `makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'UserManager':
  UserManager/migrations/0023_auto_20200425_1245.py
    - Add field create_date to student
    - Add field created_by to student
    - Add field update_date to student
    - Add field updated_by to student
    - Add field create_date to teacher
    - Add field created_by to teacher
    - Add field update_date to teacher
    - Add field updated_by to teacher
```

And `migrate`:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'create_date' in class 'Student' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'.
```

**3.Third successful solution (Bad practice)**

Rename all fields that had clash with fields in `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,BaseFieldsModel):
    # Some fields


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='student_user')

    teacher_create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    teacher_update_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    teacher_created_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='created_%(class)ss')  
    teacher_updated_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='updated_%(class)ss') 

    # Some other fields

class Student(models.Model): 
    user_ptr = OneToOneField('UserManager.User', primary_key=True,related_name='teacher_user')

    student_create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    student_update_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    student_created_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='created_%(class)ss')  
    student_updated_by = ForeignKey('UserManager.User', related_name='updated_%(class)ss') 
    # Some other fields
```

Then `makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'UserManager':
  UserManager/migrations/0023_auto_20200425_1335.py
    - Add field student_create_date to student
    - Add field student_created_by to student
    - Add field student_update_date to student
    - Add field student_updated_by to student
    - Add field teacher_create_date to teacher
    - Add field teacher_created_by to teacher
    - Add field teacher_update_date to teacher
    - Add field teacher_updated_by to teacher
```

and finally `migrate`:

```
  Applying UserManager.0023_auto_20200425_1335... OK
```

And done!

***What is wrong with Django?*** XD